flutter how to start a new run in Wrap widget?
flutter
Wrap(
  children: [widget1, widget2, break_Line_widget, widget3, ...])

Is there any widget to start a new run in a Wrap? equivalent to web <br/>.
Looked
How to make a new line in Wrap Widget
It is for text widgets only. In my case, they can be any widgets.
Widget that will expand to occupy all available space in a run? Expanded is for Row/Column.

In Flutter's Wrap widget, there is no built-in widget equivalent to a <br> tag in HTML that forces the following widgets to start on a new line. However, you can simulate this behavior by inserting a widget that expands to fill the remaining space on the current line, pushing the following widgets to the next line. In theory you can archive this by doing the following ...create a custom widget that acts like a line break by filling up the rest of the space in the current run then use a SizedBox with a width that effectively forces the wrapping.
You can define a custom widget called LineBreak that uses a SizedBox with a very large width. This will fill up the remaining space on the current run and push subsequent widgets to the next line. Example:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LineBreak extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(width: double.infinity);
  }
}

then use it like this
Wrap(
  children: [
    Widget1(),
    Widget2(),
    LineBreak(),  // This will force a new line
    Widget3(),
    Widget4(),
  ],
)


The LineBreak widget itself will be placed on the next run, right?

@eastwater LineBreak widget, as defined with a SizedBox of width: double.infinity, will not start on a new line by itself. Instead, it fills up all remaining space on the current run (line) of the Wrap widget, forcing any subsequent widgets to start on a new line. Thus, LineBreak essentially remains on the current run and only pushes other widgets to the next line.
